# How can i get an image from mysql database through php

Tags: php, mysql

I can insert my image in database but i dont find a way to get it.The image was inserted through the website.
My php code:

```
require_once('something.php');

    $codservico=$_GET['id'];

    $consulta="select * from xxxxx where xxxxx=".$something;
    $resultado=mysql_query($consulta);
    $nregistos=mysql_num_rows($resultado);
if($nregistos>0)
{
    for ($i=0; $i<$nregistos; $i++){
        $registo=mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
        echo '<tr class="show">';
        echo '<td class="show"><img src="data:image;base64,'.$registo['image'].'"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<td colspan='8' align='middle'>Nenhum registo encontrado</td>";
}
```

And i get something like this:
http://costumerbook.netai.net/Capturar.PNG

Comment: one of the good reasons, not to store images in the db. store them in the file system and the name\path in the db

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to specify the `Content-Type` (image format) - `data:image/png;base64`:

```
echo '<td class="show"><img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$registo['image'].'"></td>';
```